# How to load JSON object without consistent schema from S3 to PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, json, dataframe, pyspark

I have a data JSON object [1] sitting in S3 and I want to load it as a PySpark DataFrame that looks like this [2].

The closer I got was trying to load JSON as text with PySpark, transform it as string and loading it into Pandas [3][4]. The challenging part is how to "explode" values that are themselves a list of key/value pairs into separate rows in the Dataframe.

Does anybody have a cool way to do this?

Thanks for your help!

[1]

```
{
  "1": {
    "300": "foo",
    "301": "bar",
    "302": "foobar"
  },
  "3": {
    "r": "t",
    "f": "m"
  },
  "17": {
     "100", "200"
  }
}
```

[2]

```
----------------------
| id | some | thing  |
----------------------
| 1  | 300  | foo.   |
| 1  | 301  | bar.   |
| 1  | 302  | foobar |
| 3  | r    | t      |
| 3  | f    | m      |
| 17 | 100  | 200    |
----------------------
```

[3]

```
data_s3 = "s3://my-bucket/data.json"
json_spark_text = spark.read.text(data_s3).collect())
json_string = "".join(map(lambda x: x.value, json_spark_text))

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(json_string, orient='index')
```

[4]

```
                                                     0        
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | {u'300':u'foo',u'301':u'bar',u'302':u'foobar'} |
| 3  | {u'r':u't',u'f':u'm'}                          |
| 17 | {u'100',u'200'}                                |
-------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Spark does -- it's called "explode". Have a look in [pyspark.sql documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html).

Comment: You'd have to first find a way to get `{"id":1,"some":"300","thing" :"foo"}`. Which I think you'd have to actually parse the json by hand to apply those "column headers". And Spark has a builtin json reader, so you shouldn't need the collect+join